# Spring MVC not Showing JSP file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web, model-view-controller

Currently trying to learn Spring MVC but faced this problem and cant solve it. I defined a Controller with a method that should return a jsp file. But it does not, if i go to the url, that is mapped to jsp file i get Whitlabel Error Page.

Path Structure: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHS27.png)

Pom.xml (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEoih.jpg)

Dispatcher Config :(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb5rw.png)

ViewResolver: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kCYF.png)

Controller (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mefh.png)

Tried using Tomcat 8 instead of Tomcat 9, Spring 5 instead of Spring 6, RestController instead of Controller, ModelAndView instead of returning String.

And using web.xml and dispatcher servlet xml instead of config classes.

Comment: You should move WebConfig under com.example.demo

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to mention the package name as "com.example"
that package contains all packages
make a structure like first package name like"com.example.demo"
change config package as "com.example.config"
and mention in config class as @Componentscan("com.example") it is parent package name.

Answer (score 0):

After trying like tons of things I solved it. How? I created web and dispatcher servlet config xml files, instead of Java Configuration files,  but didn't use the <mvc:annotation-driven /> annotation this time. Tada it worked on Tomcat 9.0.70 Local server without any problems.